# How to redistribute data?

Tags: kernel-smoothing

My data are stored in integer. I need to make a model for it, and smoother data are more preferable.

Initially, I just evenly redistribute the data into integer section, e.g. `1 -> (0,1)`. I think this is just fine, but I'm curious that if it is legal to adjust the weight to make the data distributed more smoother? For example, adjust `(5,6)`'s distribution according to the value at `(4,5)`, and `(6,7)`.

I know there is **kernel density destimation**. But it is used to get the distribute function, not redistribute the data.

Below is the histogram of my data. The higher one are original integer values, and the lower one are redistributed.

[image]

Update:

If I don't redistribute the data, one of the plot that I made would look like this (Weilbull Plot):

[image]

If I redistributed the data evenly, it would look better:

[image]

Comment: When you say your data are "stored in integer" do you mean that the original data are effectively real numbers that have been truncated (rounded down)? Can you explain why you want to "redistribute" these data (what are you trying to do with it?)

Comment: @Glen_b well, there are no docs explicity about them. So I think it is either `(1) -> (0.5,1.5)`, or `(0, 1)`. Because the I need to do a `kde` and `empirical cumulative distribution`. Clustered data would make `kde` harder, and `empirical cumulative distribution` looks weird.

Comment: @cqcn1991 there's nothing wrong with fitting KDEs or ECDFs to discrete data. It's not ideal, but adding artificial noise certainly won't help.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Really? I thought it gonna help, and it's not `noise` I think. (evenly distributed). Is there any detailed explanation for it?

Comment: I don't see the problem with doing KDE directly on the discretized data. You will notice no difference between adding gaussian noise with s.d. $\tau$ followed by KDE with bandwidth $h_1$ as against using a somewhat wider bandwidth $h_2=\sqrt{\tau^2+h_1^2}$ on the original data. You can also do an ECDF with discrete data. [However, the issue of the way in which the data was discretized in the first place is quite important; if it was rounded off, that's quite different to being rounded down, since if you proceed as if you had one when it was really the other, you will end up with bias]